# Nodejs middleware always executed

Tags: node.js

I am learning NodeJS, and I am having trouble understanding why my middleware is always executed.
From my understanding, the middleware as I wrote it should be executed for all the routes declared after the middleware itself.

My index.js is something like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const router = express.Router();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser'); // Parse incoming request bodies in a middleware before your handlers, available under the req.body property.

const configdb = require('./config/db_develop');
const path = require('path');

const authentication = require('./routes/authentication')(router); // Import Authentication Routes
const noNeedForAuth = require('./routes/noNeedForAuth')(router);


const app = express();
const port = 30000;

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect(configdb.uri, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Could not connect to database ' + err);
  } else {
    console.log('Connected to the database ' + configdb.db);
  }
});

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false
})); // parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // parse application/json

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/frontend/buildpath'));

app.use('/noNeedForAuth', noNeedForAuth);
app.use('/users', authentication); 

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.send(path.join(__dirname + '/client/dist'));
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Listening on port ' + port + '!');
});
```

The authentication.js is:

```
const User = require('../models/user'); // Import User Model Schema
const config = require('../config/db_develop.js'); // Import database configuration
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken'); // Compact, URL-safe means of representing claims to be transferred between two parties.

module.exports = (router) => {

  router.post('/register', (req, res) => {
    //Register
  });
  router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    //Login
  });

  // MIDDLEWARE
  router.use((req, res, next) => {
    const token = req.headers['authorization']; // Create token found in headers
    // Check if token was found in headers
    if (!token) {
      res.status(403);
      res.json({
        success: false,
        message: 'No token provided'
      }); // Return error
    } else {
      // Verify the token is valid
      jwt.verify(token, config.secret, (err, decoded) => {
        // Check if error is expired or invalid
        if (err) {
          res.json({
            success: false,
            message: 'Token invalid: ' + err
          }); // Return error for token validation
        } else {
          req.decoded = decoded; // Create global variable to use in any request beyond
          next(); // Exit middleware
        }
      });
    }
  });

  /* ===============================================================
     Route to get user's profile data
  =============================================================== */
  router.get('/profile', (req, res) => {
    //Profile, protected route
  });

  return router; // Return router object to main index.js
}
```

And my noNeedForAuth.js is

```
module.exports = (router) => {
  /* ===============================================================
     Route to get all sections' names
  =============================================================== */
  router.get('/something', (req, res) => {
    // Do something
        res.json({
          message: 'foobar'

    });
  });

  return router; // Return router object to main index.js
}
```

From my understanding, a query to /noNeedForAuth/something should be executed without passing from the middleware, so without the need for Authentication. But this is not happening, the middleware is executed first, always.

What am I missing?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are applying your middleware without any mount path to your router. It will execute for any route.

Try something like:

```
// MIDDLEWARE
  router.use('/protected', (req, res, next) => {
    const token = req.headers['authorization']; // Create token found in headers
    // Check if token was found in headers
    if (!token) {
      res.status(403);
      res.json({
        success: false,
        message: 'No token provided'
      }); // Return error
    } else {
      // Verify the token is valid
      jwt.verify(token, config.secret, (err, decoded) => {
        // Check if error is expired or invalid
        if (err) {
          res.json({
            success: false,
            message: 'Token invalid: ' + err
          }); // Return error for token validation
        } else {
          req.decoded = decoded; // Create global variable to use in any request beyond
          next(); // Exit middleware
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

All your routes, where the user have to be authenticated, are behind `/protected`.